# Matlab nested function handle

Tags: matlab, function, nested, handle

We are working on a assignment for datacommunications where we have to declare a nested function handle in matlab.
We did a few tests on how matlab handles this but nothing works.

This is one of the tests:

```
clear;
f = @(x) x.^2;
d = @(x,u) f(x) + u;
disp(d(x,u));
```

With this test matlab gives a undefined function or variable x.
What do we have to do to fix this?

Kind regards

Full code:

```
[~, distr] = make_probability_functions(Quantization.filename);
%distr is a matrix of certain values

x_0 = 127.5;
M = 8;
delta= 10:1:30;

q = @(i) x_0+(i-(M+1)/2);

r = @(i) x_0+((2*i-M)*delta)/2;

f = @(u,i) ((q(i)-u).^2)*distr(u);

%GRANULAR
int_gran=@(delta,i) int(f,u,q(i)-delta/2,q(i)+delta/2);
s_gran=@(delta) symsum(int_gran(delta,i),i,0,M);

%OVERLOAD
s_ol=@(delta) int(@(u)f(u,1),u,-inf,q(1)-delta/2)+int(@(u)f(u,M),q(m)+delta/2,inf);

%GKD
s_e=@(delta) s_gran(delta)+s_ol(delta);

%plot GKD
plot(delta,s_e(delta),delta,s_gran(delta),delta,s_ol(delta));
```

Error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'u'.

Error in Quantization>@(delta,i)int(f,u,q(i)-delta/2,q(i)+delta/2)

Error in Quantization>@(delta)symsum(int_gran(delta,i),i,0,M)

Error in Quantization>@(delta)s_gran(delta)+s_ol(delta) (line 59)
            s_e=@(delta) s_gran(delta)+s_ol(delta);

Error in Quantization.determine_optimal_uniform_quantizer (line 62)
            plot(delta,s_e(delta),delta,s_gran(delta),delta,s_ol(delta));

Error in script_run (line 1)
Quantization.determine_optimal_uniform_quantizer();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass *actual values* to `d`. The issue is that the `x` that you're passing to `d` is not defined. There is no issue with the anonymous functions themselves.

```
f = @(x) x.^2;
d = @(x,u) f(x) + u;

d(1, 2)
%   3
```

If you want to use `x` and `u` as inputs to `d`, you'll need to define them

```
x = 1; u = 2;
d(x, u)
```

Comment: I understand, but when I want to pass the function d(x,u) in general to an integral for example, it gives the same error. This was just a test, i will edit my main question and add the 'main' code where we get the error.

Comment: @Joachim I think what you are trying to achieve is to use symbolic variables , you cannot just pass the value of undeclared variables to a function , more information about [symbolic variables  here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/syms.html)

Comment: Exactly what the problem was. You made my day, thanks!